# HTML5 - Loading video only once but use it in two different tags

Tags: javascript, html, video

In a website there are 2 video tags with different id's. One is a preview monitor in a modal dialog and the other one is a mainview monitor in the website itself.

```
<video  src="" id="preView"  ></video>
<video  src="" id="mainView" ></video>
```

When the site is loaded the views are empty. Via a modal dialog users can choose their desired video from a file list as an `url`, which then is assigned to the `preview` element when clicked.

```
preView.src = url;
```

When a video is chosen one finally clicks a button to open the video in the mainView monitor.
At this point the preView.src is assigned to the mainView.src element. And the preView element gets cleared to stop any further loading.

```
mainView.src = preView.src;
preView.src = '';
```

So far it works out fine. Except the fact that videos are always loaded twice, which is waste of resources and waste of time.

How to avoid this issue ?

My first approach was to use only one video element and move it from one place to the other as necessary. But his can be done only by some costly javascript code to trigger css styles, which I want to avoid.

My second approach is to simply dereference the loaded video from  one element and reference it in the other one without getting loaded again, which always happens when one assigns it the usual way.

So the final question is how to tell the browser to load a video *only once* but use in two different video tags, sequentially ? Any hints how to achieve this ? Would be great to get some help.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to load the video only once (in the mainview) and show the preview in a separate canvas.

Something like:

```
  var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
  var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  var video = document.getElementById('video');

  video.addEventListener('play', function() {
    var $this = this;
    var cw = Math.floor(video.clientWidth / 5);
    var ch = Math.floor(video.clientHeight / 5);
    canvas.width = cw;
    canvas.height = ch;   

    (function render() {
      if (!$this.paused && !$this.ended) {
        ctx.drawImage(video,0,0,cw,ch)
        setTimeout(render, 1000 / 30);
      }
    })();
  });
```

(See [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9dhp565h/8/) for the HTML)

This approach require a bit more of coding in order to manage autostart and reset of main video when user switch to/from preview main video, 
but it allows you to use just one canvas and draw inside it all previews.

You can read this [article](http://html5doctor.com/video-canvas-magic/) for more information on html5  and  combos

Comment: This is an interesting approach. But at the moment I decided to go back to use one video monitor (element) only. It makes the allover coding more simple. But anyway I will test it later when I have time. Sor for this proposal I give a vote up point.